# Is there a way to "exclude" an element from specific view included with @include('')

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

So in `app.blade.php` I am `including` a snippet with html which is actually my footer:

```
</body>



    @include('inc.ftr')



</html>
```

There are, though, specific views that I want to load without this footer, which is included automatically in every view.

Is there a way to exclude it on a view level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. You can check URI. For example, if you want to include the view for all requests except `admin/*` URIs:

```
@unless (request()->is('admin/*'))
    @include('inc.ftr')
@endunless
```

Or you could check specific route names:

```
@unless (Route::currentRouteName() === 'some.route')
    @include('inc.ftr')
@endunless
```